# Golang + mgo querying mongodb fails when using time because of missing 'ISODate'

Tags: mongodb, go, time, mgo, gorilla

I have the following code to retrieve some data from my mongodb -

```
currentDate := time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339)
content := database.FindDocuments("content", bson.M{ "$and": []bson.M{ bson.M{"start_date": bson.M{"$lte": currentDate}}, bson.M{"end_date": bson.M{ "$gte": currentDate}}, }})
```

FindDocuments is basically `MgoSession.DB(Dbname).C(collectionName).Find(query).All(&result)` giving me a `[]map[string]interface{}`.

This gives me null, whereas in the mongo console (using the same value as returned by the currentDate variable) -

```
{ "start_date": { $lt: ISODate("2016-09-08T13:05:24+05:30") }, $and: [ { "end_date": { $gt: ISODate("2016-09-08T13:05:24+05:30") } } ] }
```

returns me -

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("57cff2bc32291a1fa0e79e90"), 
    "image_url" : "www.example.com", 
    "title" : "This is a new content", 
    "start_date" : ISODate("2016-09-06T10:58:54.701+0000"), 
    "end_date" : ISODate("2016-09-10T10:59:04.447+0000"), 
    "type" : "content"
}
```

Why is this issue coming up despite using the correct time format?

Comment: i also having this same issue ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mgo driver seems smart enough to correctly convert time.Time to mongo Date so just

```
currentDate := time.Now()
```

should work. Also  gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson has helper to get time with millisecond precision which mongo use

```
func Now() time.Time
```

so

```
currentDate := bson.Now()
```

this helper function has simple source

```
return time.Unix(0, time.Now().UnixNano()/1e6*1e6)
```

this way any Go timestamp time.Time can be obtained in millisecond

```
someDate := time.Unix(0, time.someTime.UnixNano()/1e6*1e6)
```

Comment: Hi! Its not about not getting the date correctly. In the mongo console query, I have just copy pasted the value returned by currentDate as seen from my program console.
When using this one, the time value returned is 1473326105000 and the response is still null.

Comment: Does { "start_date": { $lt: 1473326105000 }, $and: [ { "end_date": { $gt: 1473326105000 } } ] } works in console? Maybe mongo documentation is incorrect about milliseconds. How about currentDate := time.Now().Unix() or in console { "start_date": { $lt: 1473326105 }, $and: [ { "end_date": { $gt: 1473326105 } } ] }

Comment: Both of these return null on the mongo console as well :(

Comment: @GauravOjha After deeper investigation completely rewrite answer. Sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Thank you! I had figured it out that just Time.Now() works! Isn't it kind of amazing yet frustrating?!